# How to configure aliases in YAML?

Tags: yaml, circleci

I'm trying to write some aliases into my YAML file but I keep getting an error. How can I configure aliases in YAML?

```
...rest_of_code

# DEFAULTS

checkout-and-attach: &checkout-and-attach
  checkout:
    path: ~/app
  attach_workspace:
    at: ~/app


# iOS Build and Test
  build-and-test:
    macos:
      xcode: "10.2.0"
    working_directory: ~/app/ios
    steps:
      <<: *checkout-and-attach  # [ERROR]: Incorrect type expect array


...rest_of_code
```

Comment: That is a correctly formed YAML. Your problem is with its interpretation: obviously whoever is reading it (CircleCI?) expects an array where you provide something that is not an array. Specifically, if that is the place of the error, `checkout-and-attach` (and thus `steps` as well) is an object, not an array. `- <<: *checkout-and-attach` in that place would create an array. (Note: I don't work with CircleCI, so I'm just guessing as to what it might expect.)

Comment: I don't think this is valid YAML. I just pasted it [into a parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and it reported a circular reference. cc @Amadan

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found that CircleCI is pretty good with YAML references in general. I wrote [this config file](https://github.com/halfer/cd-demo-container/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) containing several, and it works fine.

Comment: @halfer Unlike JSON, YAML is fine with circular references. It may be invalid CircleCI config, but it is valid YAML.

Comment: @Amadan: thanks for your input. I was making a slightly more narrow point, which is that an online parser refused to parse it, which I would take as a warning sign. My experience of CircleCI is that it handles references very well - there is nothing I have wanted to do that I could not. Perhaps some of my examples will help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to spread an array with circleci.
In addition, I think that the references section must be before the jobs section.

Example for working config.yml with reference:

```
version: 2
references:
  init_aws: &init_aws
    run:
      name: Init aws credentials
      command: echo 1
  init_env_vars: &init_env_vars
    run:
      name: Init environment variables
      command: echo 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.11.3
    steps:
      - *init_aws
      - *init_env_vars
```